# Best way to switch between subclasses / interface implementations based on type?

Tags: polymorphism

let's say we have something like this:

```
    abstract class Object {
        void foo(){
            ...
        }
    }

    class ObjectA extends Object {
        ...
    }

    class ObjectB extends Object {
        ...
    }

    class ObjectC extends Object {
        ...
    }
```

What's the best way to switch between a set of extended classes based on a type? I don't like the following solution, it feels dirty:

```
    ...
    Object obj;

    switch(type) {
        case "A":
            obj = new ObjectA();
            break;
        case "B":
            obj = new ObjectB();
            break;
        case "C":
            obj = new ObjectC();
            break;
        default:
            Throw error? Assign some default?
    }

    obj.foo();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) - a method that creates an object based on some parameters. In your case, the method will look something like:

```
Object ObjectFactory(string type)
{
    switch(type) {
        case "A":
            return new ObjectA();
        case "B":
            return new ObjectB();
        case "C":
            return new ObjectC();
        default:
            // Indicate error somehow
     }
}
```